# Leaflet timeline slider for Mapbox map

Tags: dictionary, slider, leaflet, mapbox, timeline

I'm working with a map created using Mapbox and am trying to implement code from for a leaflet timeline slider from dwilhem89, but am having trouble because this base map is not an OpenStreetMap map.  Calling a Mapbox map for either the base layer myMap or tileLayer in the slider code doesn't work.  Any ideas?  Thank you!!

Original calling of Mapbox map:

```
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiamdpZXNla2luZyIsImEiOiJIMzEyUzJzIn0.aHScV4IcDZF3unbDoSwjEA';
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'jgieseking.dw9suh8g').setView([40.7178,-73.9554], 12);
```

Leaflet code:

```
var myMap = L.map('map').setView([52.06, 7.40], 10);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(myMap);
```

From here, I'm also wondering how to add other layers to the map from Mapbox (from the same accessToken). Below, you'll see that the only example in the code is to get GEOJSON points from a file on the server. If I just wanted to add layers in an html file, I would implement the code as shown below. Any tips?  Thanks!

Leaflet code:

```
$.getJSON("points.json", function(json) {
var testlayer = L.geoJson(json),
    sliderControl = L.control.sliderControl({
        position: "topright",
        layer: testlayer
    });
```

How I'd otherwise add HTML layers:

```
addLayer(L.mapbox.tileLayer('jgieseking.8zyoyedn'), 'Base Map: Median Household Income 2010', 1);
```

Comment: The last code you posted adds a tile layer - tile layers can't be used for the timeline slider plugin. Generally, tiles are bitmap/raster data, and the timeline plugin needs vector data, like a GeoJSON layer. Or do you actually have vector data that you want o make a timeline for?

Comment: Thanks @Liedman.  So I had a large Excel file (with dates, locations, etc.) that I believe Mapbox made into tileLayers -- is there a way to use the Excel file outside of Mapbox to implement the timeline?